# Nautilus issues

Tags: nautilus

I recently used Nautilus (from `/usr/share/applications` as a double click on "File") to "make a link" for a desktop icon. This worked fine once I changed the permissions to executable. However when I installed sync stuff for rythmbox for iphone I noted in the terminal window a reference to Nautilus flash by. Not sure that is relevant but the desktop icon is no longer a filing cabinet and when executed it has lost its function as su. Also when run from terminal it functions as normal but with following messages. forgive me for I am but a newbie:

```
simon@Arthur:~$ sudo nautilus
[sudo] password for simon: 

(nautilus:4921): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
wrestool: /vmlinuz: file contains no resources

(nautilus:4921): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(nautilus:4921): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_spinner_start: assertion 'GTK_IS_SPINNER (spinner)' failed

(nautilus:4921): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(nautilus:4921): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_spinner_start: assertion 'GTK_IS_SPINNER (spinner)' failed

(nautilus:4921): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 120 was not found when attempting to remove it

(nautilus:4921): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 121 was not found when attempting to remove it

(nautilus:4921): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 122 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have the picture yet.  *I recently used Nautilus (from ~/usr/share/applications as a double click on "File") to "make a link" for a desktop icon* I am not sure what you did, you made a link to the desktop file of an application? What was the application?

Comment: Errors that you've posted , don't seem to be related to the issue you've described. As for the `.desktop` file, I'd open the original one and linked one and see if `Exec` lines are different

Comment: I apologise for the large pile of coprolite I wrote. I think I have my head around it now. What I wanted to do was create a usable desktop icon from applications outside of my home directory i.e. nautilus. I think I have achieved this by using the command "sudo nautilus in terminal and creating a link to my desktop from ~/usr/share/applications/Files. Then changing the command in properties to "sudo nautilus --new-window %U". I imagine there is a better way, would I be right in thinking that "%U" in the command is for user limiting nautilus to "home" directory only???

Answer (score -1):

Answered in comments by OP:

> I think I have my head around it now. What I wanted to do was create a usable desktop icon from applications outside of my home directory i.e. nautilus. I think I have achieved this by using the command `sudo nautilus` in terminal and creating a link to my desktop from `/usr/share/applications/Files`. Then changing the command in properties to `sudo nautilus --new-window %U`.